# yii2 :how to send variable to page for phpmailer

Tags: yii, yii2, phpmailer

this is my config for mail :

```
      'mail' => [
            'class' => 'zyx\phpmailer\Mailer',
//            'viewPath' => 'mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'config' => [
                'mailer' => 'smtp',
                'host' => 'mail.poorad.com',
                'port' => '25',
//                'smtpsecure' => 'tls',
                'smtpauth' => true,
                'username' => '***@poorad.com',
                'password' => '***',
            ],
        ],
```

and this is my code for sending mail :

```
$a = Yii::$app->mail->compose('passwordResetToken', ['mili' => 'miliii'])
            ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
            ->setTo('mysaltern@gmail.com')
            ->setSubject('Advanced email from Yii2-SwiftMailer')
            ->send();
```

but in:

```
<?php



echo $mili;
```

i have this error : `Undefined variable: mili`

how i can access to $mili in view ?

Comment: You are using proper way to do this. It should work unless you are pointing the wrong view or this `zyx\phpmailer\Mailer` is not implementing mailer interface properly. You can always use SwiftMailer which is a part of Yii 2 core.

Comment: in SwiftMailer iI could not  send mail !I have to use phpmailer !

Comment: It should not matter what software you are using, probably configuration issue.